# Set Theory Problem: Survey of $200$ people asks "Do like Apples (A), Bananas (B), and Cherries (C) , ..."

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have the following problem:

> In a survey of $200$ people asked about whether they like
>   apples (A), bananas (B), and cherries (C), the following data was obtained:
>
> $|A| = 112$, $|B| = 89$, $|C| = 71$, $|A \cap B| = 32$, $|A \cap C| = 26$, $|B \cap C| = 43$, $|A \cap B \cap C| = 20$.
>
> a) How many people like apples or bananas?
>
> b) How many people like exactly one of these fruit?
>
> c) How many people like none of these fruit?

---

My work is as follows:

a) Assuming this problem is using *inclusive or*, we get

$|A| + |B| - |A \cap B| = 112 + 89 - 32$

Reasoning:

If we take all of group A and all of group B, then we are double-counting the individuals that are simultaneously in group A and B, so we subtract this group of individuals from the total amount once, leaving us with the set of all people in group A or group B.

b) $|A| + |B| + |C| - 2|A \cap B| - 2|A \cap C| - 2|B \cap C| - 3|A \cap B \cap C| = 112 + 89 +71 - 64 - 52 - 86 - 60 = 10$

Reasoning:

Since we're trying to find the number of people who like *exactly one* of these fruit, we must be sure to exclude all of the people who like more than one. When we take the cardinality of any two sets, we are, as I said in the last problem, double-counting the elements that are simultaneously elements in both sets. However, unlike the last problem, we want to totally exclude the people who are in both groups, and so we must subtract *twice* the intersection of those 2 sets. The special-case to this is the case where individuals are simultaneously present in all 3 groups, since we are then triple-counting them, and we must therefore subtract *three* times the intersection of these 3 sets.

c) $|A| + |B| + |C| - |A \cap B| - |A \cap C| - |B \cap C| - 2|A \cap B \cap C| = 112 + 89 + 71 - 32 - 26 - 43 - 40 = 131$ people like *at least one* of A, B, or C.

Therefore, 200 - 131 = 69 people like none

Reasoning:

I've attempted to eliminate all double-counting and triple-counting of people, in order to get the total number of people who like *at least* one of the fruits. I then subtract this number from total number of people surveyed (200).

---

I must have made an error here, because I have that 169/200 people like apples or bananas, but 69/200 like none of the fruits, which makes no sense.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to provide feedback.

Comment: What's with the downvotes?

Comment: " since we are then triple-counting them, and we must therefore subtract three times the intersection of these 3 sets."  You must subtract them from the ones you were subtracting!  So you must *add* them!

Comment: @fleablood Yes, your answer clarified this for me. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Venn diagram is always helpful.....

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do the Venn-Diagram. How did you calculate (c)?

Comment: 200 minus all the numbers inside the Venn  $200 - (74+12+34+6+20+23+22) = 200 - 191$

Answer (score 1):

The quantity you want for number of people who like at least one fruit is
$$|A\cup B\cup C| = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A\cap B| - |A\cap C| - |B\cap C| + |A \cap B\cap C|$$ You subtracted two times the number of people who like all fruits, but you should actually add this quantity back in because note that any person counted in $|A\cap B\cap C|$ is also counted in $|A\cap B|$, $|A\cap C|$, and $|B\cap C|$ because they like fruits A, B, and C. Thus, you have counted them three times (in each individual $|A|$, $|B|$, $|C|$), and also subtracted them three times, so you have not counted these people who like all fruits at all. Thus, you must add them back in after doing the first six additions and subtractions.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

$|A| + |B| + |C| - 2|A \cap B| - 2|A \cap C| - 2|B \cap C| - 3|A \cap B \cap C|$

should be

$|A| + |B| + |C| - 2|A \cap B| - 2|A \cap C| - 2|B \cap C| +3|A \cap B \cap C| $

and $ |A|+|B|+|C|−|A∩B|−|A∩C|−|B∩C|−2|A∩B∩C|$ should be $ |A|+|B|+|C|−|A∩B|−|A∩C|−|B∩C|+2|A∩B∩C|$

....

Let's do b).

The people who *only* like apples is $|A| - |$people who like apples and other fruits other fruit$|$

And... well you understand the exclusion inclusion principal well enough to get that $|$people who like apples and other fruits other fruit$|= |A\cap B| + |A\cap C| - |A\cap B\cap C|$

So the people who only like apples is $|A| - (|A\cap B| + |A\cap C| - |A\cap B\cap C|) = |A| - |A\cap B| - |A\cap C| + |A\cap B\cap C|$.

And

So on...

upshot:  Alternate the signs the "deeper" you get into the inclusion/exclusion.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But doesn't $|A|+|B|+|C|−|A∩B|−|A∩C|−|B∩C|+2|A∩B∩C|$ = 211? We only surveyed 200 people.

Comment: See CptQ's answer. I think he is correct in that it should be $|A|+|B|+|C|−|A∩B|−|A∩C|−|B∩C|+|A∩B∩C|$. $|A|+|B|+|C|$ triple-counts the individuals who like all 3 fruits. $−|A∩B|−|A∩C|−|B∩C|$ then subtracts them 3 times, meaning that we have now not counted any of the individuals who like all 3 fruits; and so we add |A∩B∩C| once to account for these individuals.

Comment: I didn't go over your answer c) with a fine tooth comb.  The who like any fruit at all will be $|A|+|B|+|C| - |A\cap B| - |A\cap C|-|A\cap B \cap C|$  I'm not sure why you doubled $|A\cap B\cap C|$.   So those who don't like any will be $200$ minus that.

Comment: I still don't think that's correct. See CptQ's answer.

Comment: That's a #@#%# typo.  That is the exact same as CptQ's answer.  $|A|+|B|+|C| - |A\cap B| - |B\cap C|- |C\cap A| + |A\cap B\cap C|$.